# image in the SQL_database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to record the image in the SQL_database in vb.net.Enter as a file without a problem but I can not write in SQL.ABCreateNewBarcode is a PictureBox. I have a problem to take BackgroundImage from PictureBox to save in SQL. I save BackgroundImage in BarcodeImg folder but I can not save in SQl

```
Private Sub btnSaveBarcode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveBarcode.Click
    'Create Image Object
    Dim ABCreateNewBarcode As Object
    ABCreateNewBarcode = CreateObject("BARCODE.BarcodeCtrl.1")
    ABCreateNewBarcode.Text = txtNewBarcode.Text
    ABCreateNewBarcode.typename = "Code128"
    DirBarcodeImg = Application.StartupPath & "\barcodeimg"
    'Save Image
    If txtNewBarcode.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Click the Create Button to create a New Barcode")

    ElseIf Directory.Exists(DirBarcodeImg) = False Then
        Call Directory.CreateDirectory(DirBarcodeImg)

    Else
        ABCreateNewBarcode.SaveAsBySize(DirBarcodeImg & "\" & txtInsertPartName.Text & ".png", 300, 130)

        Dim ImageToSave As Image = ABCreateNewBarcode.BackgroundImage

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        ImageToSave.Save(ms, ImageToSave.RawFormat)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = MS.GetBuffer()

        'Add SQL Parameters
        SQL.AddParam("@name", txtInsertPartName.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@image", buffer)

        'Run Imsert Command
        SQL.ExecQuery("INSERT INTRO information (PartName,BarcodeImg) " &
                      "VALUES (@name,@image) ")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this is not the problem.That is error - MissingMemberException - An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Comment: Some of this code shows some very bad habits... holdovers from the vb6 era that are actively harmful to vb.net code.

Answer (score 0):

After chaging you request "INTO" instead of "INTRO" try this line:

```
SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", txtInsertPartName.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image
```

and replace :

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
ImageToSave.Save(ms, ImageToSave.RawFormat)
Dim buffer As Byte() = MS.GetBuffer()
```

by this:

```
Dim fs As FileStream
    fs = New FileStream(imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    'a byte array to read the image
    Dim picbyte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}

    fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
    fs.Close()
    'open the database using odp.net and insert the data
    Dim buffer As Byte() =picbyte
```